# Changing a function within an inherited class

Tags: python

I have a class that looks like this.

```
class General(Big_class):
   define func(self)
   self.x(arg)
   some_other_stuff
```

`x` is a function in `Big_class`. I want to create a new class that allows me to call similar functions in place of `x`, eg `y`, `z`. Is there a way of doing this that does not involve redefining the whole `func` function? I don't want to do this, because `some_other_stuff` is quite long and I will have to repeat this a few times.

```
class Specific(General, Big_class):
   def func(self)
   self.y(arg)
   some_other_stuff
```

Can I instead do something like this within `General` and just set `a` to whatever I want it to be within `Specific`? Or is there anything similar I can do?

```
class General(Big_class):
 a = x
   define func(self)
   self.a(arg)
   some_other_stuff
```

Comment: Your pseudocode is not very clear to me. Is there any reason why you can't just provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading your question as.

Is there a a way to keep all the functionality of `func` but do something different than the functionality provided by `x`.

Your initial path to a solution is you want to call something different there, but why not re-define `x` in your subclass?

```py
class Specific(General, Big_class):
   def x(self)
     # some different implementation
```